# How to use uwsgi to run fastapi program

Tags: fastapi, uwsgi, uvicorn

My fastapi program runs normally under gunicorn. For some reason, how do I use uwsgi to execute it?  Can anyone give me a case?

I tried to use it to start it directly. It seems that the protocol is not right.

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
uwsgi   31144 root    4u  IPv4 162597187      0t0  TCP *:irdmi (LISTEN)
uwsgi   31145 root    4u  IPv4 162597187      0t0  TCP *:irdmi (LISTEN)
```

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: From what I know, uwsgi doesn't support ASGI (the protocol for asynchronous web applications), so it won't work with FastAPI and Uvicorn. Just stick with gunicorn.